# Laravel PHP create empty new zip archive

Tags: php, laravel, zip, php-ziparchive

I don't understand why every time I run the following script, the zip file will contain all the previous files.

I want to start with an empty archive every time I run the script.  How can I do that?

I tried adding an empty folder, but that does not help.

```
// open zip
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// add pdfs to zip file
$zip->addEmptyDir('.'); // does not help
foreach($arPDFs as $thisPDF) {
    if (File::exists(config('path')['scTemp'].$thisPDF)) {
        $zip->addFile(config('path')['scTemp'].$thisPDF,$thisPDF);
    }
}

// close zip
$zip->close();

// delete all pdfs
foreach($arPDFs as $thisPDF) { 
    if (File::exists(config('path')['scTemp'].$thisPDF)) {
        File::delete(config('path')['scTemp'].$thisPDF);
    }
}

// download zip file
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipName);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($zipName));
readfile($zipName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the previous zip file is deleted before creating a new one.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; 

// Define the zip file name
$zipName = 'new_archive.zip';

// Check if the previous zip file exists and delete it
if (File::exists($zipName)) {
    File::delete($zipName);
}

// Create a new zip archive
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE);

// Add pdfs to the zip file
foreach ($arPDFs as $thisPDF) {
    if (File::exists(config('path')['scTemp'] . $thisPDF)) {
        $zip->addFile(config('path')['scTemp'] . $thisPDF, $thisPDF);
    }
}

// Close the zip archive
$zip->close();

// Download the zip file
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $zipName);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipName));
readfile($zipName);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed very logical...

Answer (score 2):

This is how zip works in general, if the file already exists, you modify it. Apart from what has been outlined in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76829718/367456) by [Karl Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633440/karl-hill) you can also open() it with the [ZipArchive::OVERWRITE flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php#ziparchive.constants.overwrite) (second parameter after the filename).

```php
$zip->open($zipName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE)
  || throw new Error("Unable to open the Zip archive!");
```

This should better reflect your intention opening it.